# Почему отправляется один и тот же элемент?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Есть список,элементы которого содержат кнопку+форму
Один из элементов списка:

```
<li>
  <form action="url" id="id-add-to-basket" data-product-id="product.id" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="url" value="api/prod/1"/>   
    <button type="button" href="#" id="add-single-product" rel="nofollow" data-product_id="" data-product_sku="" data-quantity="1"
           >ADD TO BASKET
    </button>
  </form>
 </li>
```

При нажатии на кнопку происходит ajax запрос:

```
$(document).on('click', "#add-single-product", function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            var csrf_token = getCookie('csrftoken');
            setupAjaxCsrf(csrf_token);

            var $form = $('#id-add-to-basket');

            var data = {};
            $form.serializeArray().map(function (x) {
                data[x.name] = x.value;
            });

            var url = $form.attr("action");
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: "POST",
                data: data,

            });
        });
    });
```

У элементов списка разные value(api/prod/1,api/prod/2,api/prod/3 и т.д.),но при клике на любом элементе постоянно отправляется значение первого элемента списка,т.е. он каждый раз хватает один и тот же valuе. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: вы уже изучали, что нельзя на странице делать несколько элементов с одинаковым идентификатором? ведь на то он и идентификатор, что должен выделять уникально только один

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все ID замените на классы.

Обработчик будет вот такой:

```
$(document).on('click', "button.submit-form", function(event){
    var $form = $(this).closest('form');
    //Ваш код
})
```

Comment: Заменил `parent` на `closest` потому что форму-то впоследствии могут и до-оформить.

Answer (score 1):

id - это уникальный идентификатор, который может быть всего один на всю страницу. В вашем примере видно, что вы для каждого элемента списка используете id="id-add-to-basket", по этому бросается скорее всего форма из первого li в списке. Оптимальный вариант который я вижу, это вычеслять target при клике, а потом с targeta идти вверх по родителям, пока не найдем элемент формы и вместо id селектора будем использовать класс ".add-single-product" на кнопке, а из форм удалим id, они не нужны, либо так же заменим их на класс:

```
$(document).on('click', ".add-single-product", function(event){
let target = event.target;
    $form;
while(target.tagName != 'LI'){
if(target.tagName == 'FORM') $form = target;
else target = target.parentNode;
}
}
```